# In my Quarto rendered PDF, how do I reduce the space around the title?

Tags: python, pdf, quarto

I want to edit directly in the raw NBConvert cell and I've tried so many things but nothing's worked. Below is one of the many I've tried.

```
---
title: \small xxx
format: 
  pdf:
    echo: false
    geometry: 
      - top=10mm
      - bottom=15mm
      - left=20mm
fontsize: "6pt"
preamble: |
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titlespacing{\title}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
jupyter: python3
---
```